# Excel Macro: looking for an easier solution to something that i usually would loop

Tags: excel, optimization

Is there an easier way to remove the last digit from every cell in a column, containing "м" or "." at the end, other than running a loop? Preferrably, leaving it formatted as number.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or some sample data that you're working with?

Comment: Look into the left and right statements. Nest them within an IF statement. http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/right.php

Comment: Depending on the nature of your real data, you might be able to use the `Replace` method with a wild card.

Comment: But on the other hand I am wondering why you not want to use a loop. I feel that using worksheet formula will slow down your entire workbook dramatically, whilst using a simple loop will run within seconds, even for very large datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to add the "M" or the "." back at the end of the cell content:

```
=IF(Right(CELL)="M",Left(CELL,Len(CELL)-2),IF(Right(CELL)=".",Left(CELL,Len(CELL)-2),CELL))
```

If you want to add the "M" or the "." back at the end:

```
=IF(Right(CELL)="M",CONCATENATE(Left(CELL,Len(CELL)-2),"M"),IF(Right(CELL)=".",CONCATENATE(Left(CELL,Len(CELL)-2),"."),CELL))
```

[image]

On the left the input data, on the right the result of the formulas above.